# why does my DecimalFormat not work for 2 decimal places in Java?

Tags: java, decimalformat

I have a `DecimalFormat` in `java` and when I use it, it does not work as expected.
In the input I'm getting `150000`, and I want to have the `15.00` as an outcome.
The code looks as follows:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      long x=150000;
      DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
      System.out.println("x " + x/10000);
      long y = x/10000;
      
      System.out.println(df.format(y));
    }
}
```

and still, the console shows `15` instead of `15.00`. What am I missing here?
Btw, is there any better way to make such formatter (while trying to convert `15000` to `15.00`)? Or is the best option to just divide it by `10000` in that case? Thank you for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern should be:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
```

Because as DecimalFormat's javadoc says:

| Symbol | Location | Localized? | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Number | Yes | Digit |
| # | Number | Yes | Digit, zero shows as absent |

> Btw, is there any better way to make such formatter (while trying to convert 15000 to 15.00)? Or is the best option to just divide it by 10000 in that case?

Formatting is just representing a value in a certain text form. It's not about changing a value, and 15000 and 15 are different values. So dividing like that is a proper way to get a different value.

Comment: but when I use this pattern and pass `x=15000`, the output shows me `1.00`, and I would like to see `1.50` - is there a solution to that as well?

Comment: @randomuser1 try changing the type of variable `y` to `double`.

Comment: @randomuser1, as Abra implied, you're losing precision when doing integer division, not when formatting.

Comment: you're right, I did `System.out.println(x); double y = x/10000; System.out.println(y);` and now I'm seeing in the console: `15000  1.0` <-- how can I divide it so that I see the `1.5` instead of `1.0`?

Comment: @randomuser1, `x` should be `double` or the expression should be `double y = (double)x/10000;`.

Comment: `x \ 10000.0` will also work. Maybe [edit] your answer?